# Django admin related Field over another model

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

Here are my models:

```
class Location(models.Model): 
    location_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)

class Host(models.Model): 
    host_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)

class Device(models.Model):
    device_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    host = models.ForeignKey('Host', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    model = models.ForeignKey('Model', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
```

And here is the `DeviceAdmin` class:

```
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('host','name','model', 'ip')
    list_filter=(
        ('model', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),
        ('host', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),
    )    
admin.site.register(Device, DeviceAdmin)
```

I need to see Location lookup field on Device Admin page. However, `Location` is related to `Device` over `Host`.

How can I display `Location` field to filter Device class by Location->Host on Device Admin page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain fields in `list_filters` and use ModelAdmin methods in `list_display`:

```
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('host', 'host_location', 'name', 'model', 'ip')
    list_filter = (
        ('model', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),
        ('host', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),
        'host__location',
    )

    def host_location(self, instance):
        return instance.host.location
    host_location.short_description = "Location"
    host_location.admin_order_field = 'host__location'
admin.site.register(Device, DeviceAdmin)
```

---

**Update** following the discussion in comments

To filter foreign keys (by any of its fields, chained relations included), you should checkout for a tool providing autocompletion. For instance: [`django-autocomplete-light`](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/). This will enable you to render such kind of widgets:

[image]

> **Note:** Since Django 2.0, [django-admin provides autocomplete fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) that do the same as `django-autocomplete-light` out of the box, and with less code.

Comment: I made a mistake, did you test with my latest edit? If so, could you provide more details about the error?

Comment: Yes, I tested it. Error is: Cannot resolve keyword 'location' into field. Choices are: device_id, host, host_id,...

Comment: Would need full stack trace. It looks like you have `list_display = ('host', 'location', 'name', 'model', 'ip')`, rather than `list_display = ('host', 'host_location', 'name', 'model', 'ip')`

Comment: class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('host','host_location', 'name','model', 'ip')
    list_filter = (
        ('model', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),
        ('host', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),
        ('host__location', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),
    )
    def host_location(self, instance):
        return instance.host.location
    host_location.short_description = 'Location'
    host_location.admin_order_field = 'host__location'
admin.site.register(Device, DeviceAdmin)

Comment: like this: http://dpaste.com/3GZNX4M  ? There are some more fields I did not posted.

Comment: It's weird, there is not field named `'location'` in `list_display`. Did you try to restart the server? Maybe the source code was not correctly reloaded. It happens from time to time.

Comment: of course, I even restarted PC. But why I shoud wait 'location', when it's 'host_location' in list_display?

Comment: `host_location` referers to the method `host_location(self, instance)`. Does it work when you remove `'host_location'` from `list_display`?

Comment: No. But it works when I remove ('host__location', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter), from filters. But then I don't get dropdown location field on Device edit operations.

Comment: Ok, so it comes from `list_filters`, I thought it came from `list_display`. Could you try with the latest changes I made to my post?

Comment: Yes it works as a filter only for view. But I need a select field for location for insert(add device) operation. So when I add new device I need to filter all hosts by location. Is it possible?

Comment: Ah OK, you need it in the change form? Not on the changelist? For this, I think the best is to rely on [`django-autocomplete-light`](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/) for instance. This enables you to render select widgets with autocompletion. Thus you will be able to type the name of a location to filter matching hosts.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this widget!

Comment: Here is an example, from one of my django projects: http://i.imgur.com/jXDstVm.png